# App crashes on exit after MFCMenuBar menu was shown

Tags: menu, mfc, menubar

We use CFrameWnd in extension DLL for some application, the MFCMenuBar::CreateFromMenu(...) is used to add menu bar. Everything works well.

But if some manipulations with the menu were performed and then main app exited it crashes somewhere in ntdll. Happens only in Debug build.

If menu is not not touched, the app does not have any issues. Any clue what can it be? Some conflict of menus with main app frame?

Comment: Post your code to help us understand what's going on

Comment: Attach the Debugger. Show us the call stack.

Comment: crash is in main app module, in stack is just one line > 0000000079118d7f()